# Conditional expectation of a random variable given that it is smaller than an independent random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am facing the following problem(s). Suppose we have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, such that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$. I am looking for sufficient conditions on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, say $P_{(X,Y)}$, which lead to $\mathbb{E}[X \mid X+Y <0] = 0$. My suspicion is for example that if the marginal distributions are symmetric around 0, this should be true. Is this so? What if they are both standard normal?

I am not mathematician and I am struggling to write the last expectation in an integral form. This would be already of a great help for me.

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: If they are independent then $E[X\mid Y]=E[X]$. So, the condition on $E[X\mid Y]  $ means simply that $E[X]=0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The conclusion is correct but unfortunately does not answer my question. I removed the redundant condition, although the question was correct also in the old form.

Comment: one more comment then: The joint distribution is the product of the  marginals. So you are looking for two distributions for which...